# How to get fluid box with absolute position while parent has a box-sizing of border-box?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two divs 'parent' and 'child'. Both boxes has a box-sizing property with value of border-box. Parent has fixed width and padding while I need child fluid width and absolute position. Child should be inside the parent div but instead its behaving kind a weird and took parents full width including padding which pushes it outside the parent. My markup looks like:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 45px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

You can also see it at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXCXF/1/). Please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `left: 0` to your child element to keep it aligned with the parent element. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N7RSz/).

Comment: OK, great stuff but it still not correct because its width is bigger than parent content area.

Comment: if you want the child div to match the content area you can just add

`left: 45px;
right: 45px;`

to match you parent padding then you can also remove the width